# Laravel save() one to many. Inserts to <column> instead of <column_id>.

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When i try to save a new object, i get this error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'epigrafe' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `articulo` (`titulo`, `epigrafe`, `revista`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Nuevo, 1, 1, 2016-04-11 08:23:32, 2016-04-11 08:23:32))

The insert should be on epigrafe_id (also revista_id).

Model:

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

```
class Articulo extends Model
{
 /**
 * Model table
 *
 */
public $table = "articulo";

protected $fillable = [
    'titulo',
];

public function revista()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Revista');
}

public function autores()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Autor');
}

public function epigrafe()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Epigrafe');
}
```

}

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
            'titulo' => 'required|max:100',
            'revista' => 'required',
            'epigrafe' => 'required',
        ]);


    $data = $request->all();

    $articulo = new Articulo;
    $articulo->titulo = $request->titulo;
    $articulo->epigrafe = $request->epigrafe;
    $articulo->revista = $request->revista;

    $articulo->save();

    $articulo->autores()->articulos()->attach($articulo->id);
    $articulo->autores()->attach($request->autor);

    Session::flash('message', 'Articulo creado satisfactoriamente!');
    return redirect()->to('articulo');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you code to the correct column names.

```
$articulo->epigrafe_id = $request->epigrafe;
$articulo->revista_id = $request->revista;
```

Comment: OMG, that was easy. Thank you very much, i wasted two hours of my life on that.

Comment: @MarioRada Please accept my answer if it helped you :)